# How to set NSButton action from data model using Cocoa Bindings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsbutton

i am filling NSCollectionView with using **Cocoa bindings**, everything works perfect but **NSButton**. I can set static selector using bindings panel to a button however i want to set it from my data model.

when i set this it calls doSomething: without no problem.

[image]

what if my data model changes and i want to set another @selector(doSomethingElse:) to the button? i couldn't accomplish that.

Comment: Are you asking about how to change the binding programmatically?  Or about where to do so?  Or about alerting the doSomething: method so that it takes data into consideration?

Comment: i want to bind button action from doSomething: to doSomethingElse:. Basically i want to setAction: to a NSButton.

Comment: You're just looking for the code to do that? `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` ...?

Comment: with code yes it is correct, how should i put this... lets say i have a  textField, from bindings it reads value from data model class and if value is "a" textField show it if you change value to "b" in your data model class it without writing any code it show "b". i want to do same thing for setAction: for NSButton.

Comment: Ah.  Like a valueTransformer that returns a selector.  But that would be a selectorTransformer!  *Good question*-- sorry I didn't catch what you meant.  In code, I think you could try to provide a mutable string in the options dictionary for the `NSSelectorNameBindingOption` ... so in that regard, have you tried providing a string reference for the selector field in IB?  And changing the string?  Not sure it'd work.

Comment: hi, yes i did try to give string reference but did not work. my data model is a dictionary. tried to setObject with NSSelectorFromString value and binding option did not work. eventually i ditch the idea changing selector, and doing everything in same void.